# Using Java check n value is appears n time and the number is in consecutive location in an given array

Tags: java

Question: Define an array to be packed if all its values are positive, each value n appears n times and all equal values are in consecutive locations. So for example, {2, 2, 3, 3, 3} is packed because 2 appears twice and 3 appears three times. But {2, 3, 2, 3, 3} is not packed because the 2s are not in consecutive locations. And {2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3} is not packed because 2 appears three times.
Write a method named isPacked that returns 1 if its array argument is packed, otherwise it returns 0. You may assume that the array is not null

If you are programming in Java or C#, the function signature is
int isPacked(int[ ] a)

```
    public class isPackd{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int result=isPacked(new int[ ] {2, 2, 1});
    System.out.println("Return: " + result);
    result=isPacked(new int[ ] {7, 7, 7, 7, 1, 7, 7, 7});
    System.out.println("Return: " + result);
  }//main()


  public static int isPacked(int[ ] a){

    for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
      int chkHowManyTimes=howManyTimes(a, a.length, a[i]);
      if (chkHowManyTimes !=a[i]) {
        return 0;
      } // end of if
    } // end of for

    if (isConsecutive(a)==0) {
      return 0;
    } // end of if

    return 1; 
  }//isPacked()

  public static int howManyTimes(int[] array, int length, int findNumber){
    int count=0;

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
      if (array[i]==findNumber) {
        count +=1;
      } // end of if
    } // end of for
    //System.out.println(count);
    return count;
  }//howMany..()  

  public static int isConsecutive(int[] a){
    //
    //need help here to write code for this section
    //
    return 1;
  }//isCon..()


}//class
```

I need help to check whether the number is in consecutive location or not.

Comment: Hey,Tanvir.Welcome to stackoverflow.Realy you need a method which returns 1 if the input array seems to be like this [2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4] else 0.Is it ok?

Comment: Yes that is correct. But i need to check one more thing. All the number should be in consecutive locations like if the number is {2, 3, ,3, 3, 2} then return 0. Because the last 2 is not in consecutive location. but it will return 1 for the array {2,2,3,3,3,1} because all the number are in consecutive location. @ShihabSoft

Comment: It seems like this {5,5,4,4,1,2,2,0,0,1} what will you expect it to return 1 may be or 0?

Comment: return 0 becuase
a) 1 occurs 2 times it should be 1 times
b) 0 coours 2 time.

{5,5,5,5,5,4,4,1,2,2,} will return 1

Comment: Ya ok then {5,5,4,4,1,2,2,0,0} this.May be the last question iam asking..

Comment: This question has two parts. first one is to check number n occurs n times and secondly numbers are in consecutive location meaning {3,3,1,3} will return 0 but {3,3,3,1} will return 1 because all 3 are in consecutive location @ShihabSoft

Comment: {5,5,4,4,1,2,2,0,0}  will return 0 because '0' occurs more than 0 times.

Comment: K then,wait for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And then,here is the full code below.
So, is there anything just feel free to ask here.

```
public class Consecutive
{
/***************************************************************************/
Author :- ShihabSoft
/***************************************************************************/
public static void main(String[] someArgs)
{
int[] args=new int[someArgs.length];
    for(int i=0;i<someArgs.length;i++)
        args[i]=Integer.parseInt(someArgs[i]);
        int swit=checkArrConsecutive(args);
        if(swit==0 || swit==1)
        System.out.println("All "+args.length+" values appeared accordingly in the array");

switch(swit)
{
    case 0:
        System.out.println("Array is not well packed.");
    break;
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Array is well packed");
}
}
//As per your needs we need two functions
static int checkArrConsecutive(int[] args)
{
int curr=0,temp=0;
if(args!=null)
{
int numIndex=0;
    for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++)
    {
        curr=args[i];
        temp=0;
        if(checkNoccursNtime(args,curr)==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry the number :- "+curr+" at index '"+i+"' repeats more or less than '"+curr+"' times");
            return 2;
        }

        for(int j=numIndex;j<args.length;j++)
        {
        if(temp==curr)
            break;
        if(args[j]!=curr)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
            temp++;

        }
        if(curr!=(args.length!=(i+1) ? args[i+1] : args[i]))
        numIndex=i+1;

    }
return 1;


}
return 0;
}
static int checkNoccursNtime(int[] args,int n)
{
if(args!=null)
{
int curr=0,temp=0;
    temp=0;
    curr=n;
    for(int j=0;j<args.length;j++)
    {
        if(args[j]==curr && temp != curr)
            temp++ ;
        else if(args[j]==curr)
            return 0;
    }
return temp==curr ? 1 : 0;
}
return 0;
}

}
```

Just compile the above code and run passing values like this.

```
java Consecutive 5 5 5 5 5 1 2 2 3 3 3
```

Comment: Hi @ShihabSoft i have checked your code and its perfect. The way you have checked Consecutive number is simply brilliant. Many many thanks for giving me your time and effort brother :)

Comment: Its ok.Welcome bro @Tanvir.We are here to share,express and study the knowledge.Jz come up with another complication.I will be here helping all.And once again Welcome to StackOverflow.And don't forget to upvote

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Packed {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int[] a = { 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,7, 7 };
    int tt = isPacked(a);
    System.out.println(tt);

}

private static int isPacked(int[] a) {

    int n;
    int count = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int initialindex;
    int finalindex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] < 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        n = a[i];
        k = 0;
        initialindex = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            k++;
            if (n == a[j]) {
                i++;
                finalindex = k;
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (n != count || (finalindex - initialindex) != count) {
            return 0;
        }
        i--;
        count = 0;
    }
    return 1;
 }

}
```